Understanding the Impact of Parameter Adjustment in KMA Aligner for Gene Analysis
I am currently using the KMA aligner (k-mer alignment) from Clausen et al. (https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-018-2336-6) to analyze gene sequences (metagenomics) and am exploring the various parameters that can be adjusted to ensure the reliability of the results. The aligner offers several parameters such as, for example, minimal template identity, minimum read score normalized to alignment length etc (https://gensoft.pasteur.fr/docs/kma/1.3.4/KMAspecification.pdf), together with scoring algorithm adjustments including reward, penalty, gap open, and gap extend.
For instance, the default settings are:

-reward: 1 (for matching a nucleotide)
-penalty: -2 (for a nucleotide mismatch)
-gapopen: -3 (penalty for opening a gap)
-gapextend: -1 (penalty for extending a gap)

I understand that changing these values can significantly alter the alignment scores, but I am trying to grasp the broader implications of modifying these parameters.
My questions are:

What is the "philosophical" / practical reasoning behind the ability to adjust these parameters in the KMA aligner?
Why might one want to deviate from the default settings?
How do changes in these parameters affect the interpretation of gene alignment results?

Any insights or examples of how adjusting these parameters has impacted gene alignment studies would be greatly appreciated.

These questions are too broad to be appropriately answered on Bioinformatics Stack Exchange. Please restrict your question posts to a single specific problem that you are having. For subjective or philosophical discussion, post on a discussion-based forum such as reddit.
